# How to improve object detection?

Tags: opencv, object-detection, contour

I want to improve my project which is designed for object detection.

Firstly, to get my actual result I use `absdiff`, and next I use the following operations are in my code below:

```
cv::threshold(subtractionResultEdges, threshold, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);

    Sobel(threshold, sobel, CV_32F, 1, 0);

    minMaxLoc(sobel, &minVal, &maxVal);

    sobel.convertTo(sobel, CV_8U, 255.0 / (maxVal - minVal), -minVal * 255.0 / (maxVal - minVal));

    dilate(subtractionResultEdges, subtractionResultEdges, verticalStructreMat, Point(-1, -1));


    erode(subtractionResultEdges, filteredResult, verticalStructreMat, Point(-1, -1));

    Canny(filteredResult, filteredResult, 33, 100, 3);
```

My last operation is `findContours(canny_output, *contours, *hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));`

This is my result after use every function and foreground which I get with using `accumulate` function (20 frames) :

foreground:
http://j71i.imgup.net/foregroundc3dc.PNG

subtraction:
http://p81i.imgup.net/subtractio2866.PNG

Sobel:
http://g51i.imgup.net/sobela1fb.PNG

threshold:
http://p46i.imgup.net/treshold14c9.PNG

dilate, erode and Canny:

http://q68i.imgup.net/canny2e1a.PNG

findContours:
http://v76i.imgup.net/contours6845.PNG

Background is also obtained from `accumulate` function.

Could you help me get better corner or contours detection? I need it, to get object size in pixels.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide an example of a detection you desire?

Comment: I want to detect packages. In general the object should be a cuboid. It can be not parallel to the edge of camera, so I do not want to use `boundingRect ` function, because in my mind, the error in detection is too high.

Comment: Try eroding, without using Canny and then find contours, it should give a bounding rectangle as it just becomes a blob of white pixels.

Comment: I tried do it, like you said, but the result was worst, than before. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Shreyas Kapur this is the result: http://p16i.imgup.net/resultdc78.PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a larger kernel for [dilate/erode](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#erode) part, maybe (11, 11) or even bigger, or alternatively do multiple iterations (this can be set as a parameter. This should connect the individual parts of your detected object better and then you'll have less contours.

To calculate area, you can then use [contourArea()](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1&gsc.tab=0)

Comment: I tried use bigger dilate and erode filter, and i get some result. Could you tell me how can I get height and width from `contourArea` ()? Maybe use other function, on this result which I get from using `findContours `function.

Comment: Not from `contourArea` but from [`boundingRect`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#cv2.boundingRect) you can get width and height.

Comment: `boundingRect` I tried it before, but it didn't work fine for me.

Comment: what do you mean by didn't work? it will return the bounding rectangle of a contour.. so maybe your contours were bad in the first place?

Comment: I mean that this function cannot bounding rectangle of my object, because contours are in not complete I think. They are not closed.

Comment: aah try CV_RETR_EXTERNAL or CV_RETR_LIST in find contours then

Comment: I tried to use CV_RETR_LIST. It is quite good and this is the result: http://m00i.imgup.net/resultP9280.PNG. Like you see, the object has edges parallel to camera edge but `boundingRect ` doesn't work very well (see green rectangle). Next problem, look whats happened, when we had edges of object in other position (at an angle) http://k75i.imgup.net/resultA86c8.PNG. In this case, the error is too big.